# Как сделать чтобы элементы выходили за пределы родителя по горизонтали?

Tags: css, html

Хочу сделать простую карусель: есть контейнер, есть его содержимое обернутое в свой контейнер, который я и хочу двигать по горизонтали с помощью JavaScript.

Но, слайды все равно переносятся на другую строку, когда упираются в контейнер.

CSS карусели:

```
.slider {
    border: 2px solid black;
    background: gray;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden; /*Прячем что вылезло */
}
```

CSS слайдов:

```
.slider .texts{    
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width:  auto; /* По идее должен растягиваться от содержимого */
    height: 200px; 
}

.slider .texts li{
    list-style-type: none;
    /* Размеры слайда */
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slider" id="slider">
    <ul class="texts" id="texts">

            <li>Первый</li>
            <li>Второй</li>
            <li>Третий</li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно запретить им перенос `.slider .texts {white-space: nowrap}`

Comment: Большое спасибо. Но почему так происходит? Потому что позиционирование абсолютно-относительное? То есть внутренний элемент воспринимает контейнер как окно браузера? Плюс таковы правила для строчных элементов?

Comment: Позиционирование не причем - у вас непосредственно слайды не спозиционированы, только контейнер для слайдов имеет позиционирование. Строчные элементы переносятся если не хватает места, вот и все.